# Release static IP

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

I've a static IP address assigned by my internet provider. For security reasons I'd like to change the address to another one. How can i do that if it's not DHCP-ed? There are "Release WAN Lease" and "Renew WAN Lease" buttons in my modem/router control panel page but are they relevant in case the address is assigned statically?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your ISP about this. You will always have the same IP, as your ISP has assigned this IP to your hardware address.

One potential option is to spoof your hardware address, however, this is not really a viable option as I'm sure your ISP would take action once they discovered that you were using bogus hardware addresses.

Comment: So what the buttons "Release WAN Lease" and "Renew WAN Lease" are used for in case of static IP?

Comment: They're not really of any use in this case. The mechanism is pretty much you router relinquishing its IP and then asking for an IP again. If it was dynamic this would ensure that your router and your ISP are in agreement regarding which IP to use.

Comment: So ISP assigns a new IP to me & I press the buttons to reflect the change in my router?

Comment: Can You please answer my last question?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Changing your public IP yourself is a bad idea or impossible. Contact your ISP.

There are two possibilities for static IP:

- Actual static IP:

  The IP is configured in your box itself. You could change it by fiddling with the box settings, but the IP address is most likely hardcoded.
- DHCP Reservation:

  The box is configured to get its IP from the ISP's DHCP server. However, the ISP configured his DHCP to tie your box's MAC address to an IP that never changes. The "Release" and "Renew" buttons on your box's settings are used to update the IP in case it changed.

About problems:

Some ISPs use the box's IP or MAC address to identify it in their network and allow it to communicate with the Internet. If you use tools to change your IP or MAC address your ISP won't know who you are and they won't be able to tell you are allowed to access the Internet.

Comment: "The "Release" and "Renew" buttons on your box's settings are used to update the IP in case it changed" - so i don't have to call my ISP to assign me the new IP but all i need is just to press "Release" and then "Renew" button to get the new IP?

Comment: No. "In case it changes" means your ISP has assigned a new IP to your box. If no change has beens made on the ISP's side, no change will happen on your side either, even if you press those buttons.

Comment: So ISP assigns a new IP to me & I press the buttons to reflect the change in my router?

Comment: Yes. The obvious prerequisite being that they *effectively* assign you a new IP, and if they gave you a static IP you will need to contact them to see what are the possibilities.